# Enterprise Architect: Change diagram type (MetaType) by script

Tags: enterprise-architect

i have to change the diagram type of a lot of diagrams within my Enterprise Architect model. The change can be made manually using following option (that works as expected):

Select diagram - Diagram - Advanced - Change Type...

As I have to change a lot of diagrams I have created a script which searches for all concerned diagrams and change the type automatically. I wrote already a lot of JScript EA scripts for changing some modeling elements. Unfortunately, this feature seems not be available over the scripting interface.

I have to change the "MetaType" of the the diagram object. But this is read-only (see http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12/automation_and_scripting/diagram2.html). Therefore, I got an error.

```
var currentDiagram as EA.Diagram
currentDiagram = theDiagram
currentDiagram.MetaType = MY_DIAGRAM_METATYPE // ERROR
```

In the next step I searched for appropriate functionalities in the Repository interface (http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12/automation_and_scripting/repository3.html) and in the project interface. But I found nothing appropiate.

I am using Enterprise Architect 12.0.1215 and I used JScript.

Has anyone already tried this by script?
Have I missed something?
Is there another approach to achieve the diagram type change by script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that in two steps (if you change to different MDG diagram types). E.g. to change a Class diagram to a BPMN2.0::BPEL you first change `Diagram_Type` from *Logical* to *Analysis*. Additionally you need to add *MDGDgm=BPMN2.0::BPEL;* to `StyleEx`.  In case your old diagram is from another MDG you need to modify the existing `MDGDgm` attribute in `StyleEx`.

As Uffe noted, the diagram type in the API is r/o. So if you need to change that you would need to do something like

```
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_diagram SET Diagram_Type='Analysis' WHERE Diagram_ID=<theId>")
```

where `<theId>` would be the correct diagram ID.

Comment: As noted in the question, the Type attribute of the Diagram class is read-only, so in order to change it you need to update it in the database directly.

Comment: The proposed solution worked for me! Thank you very much. I have no need to change the type of the diagram but only the meta type (other MDG) and for that the change in the StyleEx property is sufficient. As for the concerned diagrams an empty "MDGgm" entry is available, I could use following code: `currentDiagram.StyleEx = currentDiagram.StyleEx.replace( "MDGDgm=;", "MDGDgm=" + FSM_DIAGRAM_METATYPE + ";" )`

Comment: Does this work on Sparx 14? I can update using Repository.execute (on MS SQL) and it updates, however repository.update seems to change it back to the original type. it seems there is a hidden reference to the old type?

Comment: @Hightower That has nothing to do with the version. Calling `Update` will write back the info which was loaded previously with changes made. So you need to `Execute`, `GetDiagram...`, make changes, and finally `Update`.